# does onDisconnect event on SignalR2 releases all of its resources upon disconnect?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have a concurrent dictionary List on my controller that stores list of online users. For example when Client A and Client B connects there are 2 online clients present on the list, but when i disconnect B and then re- connect again it must still show 2 online clients but in my case, only Client B detected as online user(disconnected then reconnected). I am using IIS server 7.5.. Please help me with this, do i need to use a database rather than dictionary? I think it resets the dictionary to zero if one user disconnects and reconnects again.... :(  Below is my hub class code

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    //add online client
   private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> personLists
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public void Connect(string Username, int ID)
    {
      string id = Context.ConnectionId;
        if (!personLists.ContainsKey(Username))
        {
            personLists.TryAdd(Username, id);
            Clients.Caller.viewOnlinePersons(personLists.Where(p =>  p.Key != Username));
            Clients.Others.enters(Username);
        }
        else
        {

            string notif = "user: "+Username+" is already used";
            Clients.Caller.onUse(notif);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The concurrent dictionary should work just fine. It'd be good if you could post some code, but if you go this route with concurrent dictionary, make sure it's `static` (the `Hub` classes get created and destroyed per signal) and I think it'd be better suited placed on the hub itself and private (and of course `static`, again). You can also use Dependency Injection with SignalR which will be a lot cleaner.

You'll only need database as a backplane if you plan on running the application on multiple servers where of course a memory of a single server is not accessible by the other servers and a duplicate dictionary would be created for each server, so in that case you need to take the storage and move it up a bit in the architecture to be accessible by all the servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, my dictionary is static..but what do you mean (the Hub classes get created and destroyed per signal)? for example if Client A and Client B is online,therefore the concurrent dictionary contains 2 record, but if one client disconnects, and reconnects again,only that client is stored in the static dictionary despite that the other client is still connected.. so the dictionary contains 1 record instead of 2.. i debug  it using an alert message box on javascript to show the count of static dictionary i used..

Comment: so my conclusion is, every time user disconnects ,it resets the dictionary to zero ,how about when there are 3 users are online and one of them is disconnects then reconnects, dictionary resets to zero..

Comment: The `Hub` classes itself exist only during the time a hub method is processed, and are destroyed afterwards. That's why I anticipated you were using non-static `ConcurrentDictionary`, since that would get instantiated every time someone connected/disconnected/invoked a hub action. Can you please upload the entire solution somewhere for me to have a look at?